# Get User Final Location IOS

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm doing a query inside of:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    if (!gotLocation){
        gotLocation = true;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        // DO QUERY
    }
}
```

But I would like to know when the final location is set, or when a more accurate one is made. I'm trying to query only once and need a precise location for the query. I know I can use `[locations lastObject]`, but how can I determine when the final or a more precise location is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the location's `horizontalAccuracy`. The smaller the value the more accurate. You should hold a reference to the last location you received then when a new location comes in that is more accurate, the `horizontalAccuracy` is smaller, updated your reference.

Then once you receive a location with a `horizontalAccuracy` close enough for your use case then you can call `stopUpdatingLocation` since you have your location, then do your query.

For example:

```
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
if (location.horizontalAccuracy < self.lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
    self.lastLocation = location;
    if (self.lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= kDesiredLocationAccuracy) {
        // execute query or additional logic
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You would need to add some sort of timer or other limit as it is possible that the desired accuracy may never be reached. If you are happy to target iOS9 and later then you can use `requestLocation` and all the hard work is done for you.

Comment: @Paulw11, your suggestion is interesting. Is it ok if you can post an example of that timer and for checking when the desired accuracy is not getting any better.

Comment: Personally, I would target iOS 9 as a minimum and use `requestLocation`